# Identify a succulent with gray-green paired ovate leaves

Tags: houseplants, plant-care

I saw this potted plant at a local grocery store. It was USD $10 and there was only .

Can someone identify this plant? Is it fast-growing? Does it have flowers? Is it indoor or outdoor?

Does it have any practical uses?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: One id per question, please!

Comment: Please ask a separate question for each plant. Policy is to have one plant per id question; see https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/826/for-identification-please-only-post-one-plant-per-question-and-be-specific-whe for more information.

Comment: Sorry about that. Will edit.

Comment: The shape of the leaf resembles Sedum.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a Kalanchoe, specifically Kalanchoe fedtschenkoi - in full sun, it should display more of a purple coloration. Flowers may be orange, pink or red, and it needs to be kept well drained, in free draining potting soil, in a pot with drainage holes, and not left sitting in water in any outer tray or pot. It grows outdoors in hot places like Brisbane, Australia, and is considered an invasive weed there, but in more temperate regions, or areas where temperatures are low in winter, best kept as a houseplant, though it could be placed outside during warm summer months for a while. All parts of the plant are poisonous see here https://garden.org/plants/view/112178/Lavender-Scallops-Kalanchoe-fedtschenkoi/